# How to stack a timeline/timeline events/and graphs in R

Tags: r, data-visualization

I want to create a timeline to show all the results of one of my studies. I just want to display a timeline, event by group, and line charts of some data I obtained.
I've tried doing it in illustrator/photoshop but it's just time consuming and not what I aiming for.

Here is the thing I've tried in illustrator, just to show you the type of diagram I'm aiming for:

[image]

So the figure I want to be able to do have this structure:

- Timeline
- Timeline events grouped by type
- Line charts of my data
- and so on...

Have you some suggestion to do it in R? Maybe a package? Or another tool?

Comment: Maybe the `timevis` package could be helpful.

Comment: i've checked this package, promising for the timeline but not for aggregating linecharts..